# How to copy complete database with different name from mysql console?

Tags: mysql, copy

I am using command prompt in my local machine and I am trying different ways to copy an existing database with diffrent name.

1. Using mysqldump I am able to dump an existing database as oldDB.sql file and successfully import to the newDB database
2. Now I tried another way in which I entered to mysql console by typing the command
   mysql -hDBHOST -uDBUSER -p; so now my terminal looks like as shown below

mysql>

Now my question is can we copy a database from mysql prompt? I have searched on the net but did not found any solution. As everybody explaining about the first Method which I have already tried and got success. I am curious how can I copy or clone any database while we are in MYSQL> console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no single command to do this. You can copy one table at a time:

```
CREATE TABLE db2.mytable LIKE db1.mytable;
INSERT INTO db2.mytable SELECT * FROM db1.mytable;
```

And you could generate these statements from a list of tables you get from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.

Really the MySQL CLI isn't the best tool for this task. I'd use a Python script (or whatever your favorite programming language is).